# cPanel - No permission to download backup

Tags: apache, cpanel, filezilla, fileserver

Thanks in advance for any help, you guys are awesome!

A previous web developer made a backup of the site in question to the server months ago, and the permissions for this backup are 600. I can't change the permissions or download the file, although I can still move it between folders.

I've read having low disk space is sometimes the problem, but in this case there are 2 GB left, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is an other way to download backup from server to local machine, if you are able to move backup file in folders then move it to your website's home directory like '/home/user/public_html/backup.zip' and then browse it in browser and download the backup file.

http://yourdomain.com/backup.zip

It will provide you download option.